# Pytest error in tests for Single choice question in Django

Tags: python, django, pytest

This is going to be Pytest for single choice question. It cannot be completed due to two reasons - the first one is that the test cannot choose any option from available language_name fields:

[image: Single choice]

## views.py

```
class AddSingleChoiceQuestionView(View):
    template_name = "single_choice_form.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = SingleChoiceQuestionForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            form = SingleChoiceQuestionForm(request.POST)
            print(request.POST)
            print(form.is_valid())
            print(form.errors)
            if form.is_valid():
                question = form.save()

                # Ermitteln Sie die ausgewählte Option aus den Checkboxen
                selected_option = int(request.POST.get("correct_option"))

                for i in range(1, 6):
                    option_text = request.POST.get(f"option_{i}")
                    is_correct = i == selected_option  # Überprüfen Sie, ob diese Option die ausgewählte ist
                    question.singlechoiceoption_set.create(option_text=option_text, is_correct=is_correct)

                # return HttpResponseRedirect("success_page") hier doesn't work
                return redirect("success_page")

            return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
        else:
            return redirect("index")
```

## Conftest.py

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.fixture
def staff_user(db):
    user = User.objects.create_user(username='staffuser', password='staffpassword', is_staff=True)
    return user

@pytest.fixture
def regular_user(db):
    user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='testpassword')
    return user
```

## test_views.py for single chocie

```
import pytest
from django.test import Client
from django.urls import reverse
from ..models import MultiQuesModel, Answer, SingleChoiceQuestion
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ..views import AddMultiQuestionView
from ..forms import AddMultipleForm, SingleChoiceQuestionForm

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestAddSingleChoiceQuestion:

    @pytest.mark.singlechoice
    def test_add_single_choice_question(self, client, staff_user):
        client.login(username='staffuser', password='staffpassword')
        url = reverse("singleform")  # Ersetzen Sie "singlechoice_form" durch den tatsächlichen Namen Ihrer URL-Entsprechung
        data = {
            "question_text": "Pytest's question",
            "language_name": 2,
            "correct_option": 3,  # Correct answer
            "option_1": "Option 1",
            "option_2": "Option 2",
            "option_3": "Option 3",
            "option_4": "Option 4",
            "option_5": "Option 5",
        }

        print("Sending POST request to the view...")
        response = client.post(url, data)
        print("Received response from the view:", response)
        print(response.content)  # Contente of the response 

        
        assert response.status_code == 302  # Awaiting (Redirect)
        assert response.url == reverse("success_page")  # Erwartet eine Weiterleitung zur "success_page"

      
       
        question = SingleChoiceQuestion.objects.get(question_text="Test question")
        assert question is not None
        options = question.singlechoiceoption_set.all()
        assert options.count() == 5
```

## single_choice_form.html

```
{% extends 'dependencies.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Create Single Choice Question</h2>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.question_text.label_tag }} {{ form.question_text }}
    {{ form.language_name.label_tag }} {{ form.language_name }}

    <div id="answers-container">
        <label>Options:</label>
        <ul id="options-list">
            {% for field in form.options %}
                <li>
                    {{ field.choice_label }}
                    <input type="text" name="option_{{ forloop.counter }}" maxlength="200">
                    <input type="radio" name="correct_option" value="{{ forloop.counter }}">
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    const answersContainer = document.getElementById("answers-container");
    const optionsList = document.getElementById("options-list");
    const options = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="correct_option"]');

    options.forEach((option, index) => {
        option.addEventListener("change", function () {
            
            const textField = optionsList.querySelector(`input[type="text"][name="option_${index + 1}"]`);
            textField.disabled = !this.checked;

            
            optionsList.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach((otherTextField, otherIndex) => {
                if (otherIndex !== index) {
                    otherTextField.disabled = false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

## Manual test

```
[11/Oct/2023 00:45:27] "GET /single-form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6885
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['CV6CY7XpRf3RpOxJwblBNQHggmgRqKknIbzyxPxiqog6WJvqyWPQ5XYTrc8s5V08'], 'question_text': ['2Single choice?'], 'language_name': ['3'], 'option_1': ['Coorect'], 'option_2': ['665'], 'option_3': ['JS'], 'option_4': ['y654'], 'correct_option': ['4'], 'option_5': ['Elephant']}>
True

[11/Oct/2023 00:47:34] "POST /single-form/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[11/Oct/2023 00:47:34] "GET /success-page/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
[11/Oct/2023 00:47:36] "GET /questionmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2818
```

## Pytest

```
pytest -k "singlechoice" -v
================================================================================= test session starts =================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.3, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.3.0 -- .venv\Scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
django: settings: Quiz.settings (from ini)
rootdir: Quiz\Learntest
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: Faker-19.6.1, Flask-Dance-6.2.0, django-4.5.2
collected 4 items / 3 deselected / 1 selected                                                                                                                                          

tests/test_views.py::TestAddSingleChoiceQuestion::test_add_single_choice_question FAILED                                                                                         [100%]

====================================================================================== FAILURES =======================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________ TestAddSingleChoiceQuestion.test_add_single_choice_question _____________________________________________________________ 

self = <Learntest.tests.test_views.TestAddSingleChoiceQuestion object at 0x000001EB31B0E490>, client = <django.test.client.Client object at 0x000001EB31CCB390>
staff_user = <User: staffuser>

    @pytest.mark.singlechoice
    def test_add_single_choice_question(self, client, staff_user):
        client.login(username='staffuser', password='staffpassword')
        url = reverse("singleform") g
        data = {
            "question_text": "Pytest's question",
            "language_name": 2,
            "correct_option": 3, 
            "option_1": "Option 1",
            "option_2": "Option 2",
            "option_3": "Option 3",
            "option_4": "Option 4",
            "option_5": "Option 5",
        }

        print("Sending POST request to the view...")
        response = client.post(url, data)
        print("Received response from the view:", response)
        print(response.content)  # Hinzugefügter Code: Drucken Sie den Inhalt der Antwort

        
>       assert response.status_code == 302  # Erwartet eine Weiterleitung (Redirect)
E       assert 200 == 302
E        +  where 200 = <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">.status_code

tests\test_views.py:76: AssertionError
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr setup -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Sending POST request to the view...
<QueryDict: {'question_text': ["Pytest's question"], 'language_name': ['2'], 'correct_option': ['3'], 'option_1': ['Option 1'], 'option_2': ['Option 2'], 'option_3': ['Option 3'], 'option_4': ['Option 4'], 'option_5': ['Option 5']}>
False
<ul class="errorlist"><li>language_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
Received response from the view: <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
b'\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <title>\n            Quiz with Django\n        </title>\n        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/boo
tstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        \n\n<style>\n  .greet{\n 
   font-size: 18px;\n    color: #fff;\n    margin-right: 20px;\n  }\n</style>\n\n<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: rgba(34, 97, 21) ;">\n  <butt
on class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">\n    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>\n  </button>\n  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">\n\n    <ul class="navbar-nav">\n\n          <li class="nav-item active">\n         
   <a class="nav-link" href="/index/">Main page</a>\n          </li>\n\n\n          <li class="nav-item active">\n          \n          </li>\n          <li class="nav-item active">\n 
           <a class="nav-link" href="/multi-form/">Multi question</a>\n          </li>\n\n          <li class="nav-item active">\n            <a class="nav-link" href="/single-form/">S
ingle question</a>\n          </li>\n          \n\n\n          <li class="nav-item">\n            <a class="nav-link" href="/accounts/login/">Login</a>\n          </li>\n\n          <l
i class="nav-item active">\n              <a class="nav-link" href="/register/">Register</a>\n          </li>\n\n          <li class="nav-item active">\n          \n          </li>\n  
        <li class="nav-item active">\n            <a class="nav-link" href="/question-form/">Text question</a>\n          </li>\n          \n\n          <li class="nav-item active">\n 
             <a class="nav-link" href="/multi-site/">Multi Quiz</a>\n          </li>\n\n          <li class="nav-item active">\n              <a class="nav-link" href="/notes/">Corpora
te Notes</a>\n          </li>\n\n          <li class="nav-item active">\n            \n          </li>\n              <a class="nav-link" href="/questionmanager/">Questionmanager</a>\n
          </li>\n          \n\n\n    </ul>\n  </div>\n\n  <span class="greet">Hello, staffuser</span>\n  <span ><a  class="greet" href="/logout/">Logout</a></span>\n  <span ><a  class=
"greet" href="/my-account/">My account</a></span>\n\n</nav>\n\n        \n<h2>Create Single Choice Question</h2>\n\n<form method="post">\n    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewareto
ken" value="0yE51WtKimn3QB7vI0EwxuQwVy4Cdab8PU9gyCvAO9A8SjmjpyoNM4jIeS3fVTQk">\n\n    <label for="id_question_text">Question text:</label> <input type="text" name="question_text" value
="Pytest&#x27;s question" maxlength="255" required id="id_question_text">\n    <label for="id_language_name">Language name:</label> <select name="language_name" required id="id_languag
e_name">\n  <option value="">---------</option>\n\n</select>\n\n    <div id="answers-container">\n        <label>Options:</label>\n        <ul id="options-list">\n            \n       
         <li>\n                    Option 1\n                    <input type="text" name="option_1" maxlength="200">\n                    <input type="radio" name="correct_option" value="1">\n                </li>\n            \n                <li>\n                    Option 2\n                    <input type="text" name="option_2" maxlength="200">\n              
      <input type="radio" name="correct_option" value="2">\n                </li>\n            \n                <li>\n                    Option 3\n                    <input type="text" name="option_3" maxlength="200">\n                    <input type="radio" name="correct_option" value="3">\n                </li>\n            \n                <li>\n             
       Option 4\n                    <input type="text" name="option_4" maxlength="200">\n                    <input type="radio" name="correct_option" value="4">\n                </li
>\n            \n                <li>\n                    Option 5\n                    <input type="text" name="option_5" maxlength="200">\n                    <input type="radio" na
me="correct_option" value="5">\n                </li>\n            \n        </ul>\n    </div>\n\n    <input type="submit" value="Submit">\n</form>\n\n<script>\n    const answersContai
ner = document.getElementById("answers-container");\n    const optionsList = document.getElementById("options-list");\n    const options = document.querySelectorAll(\'input[type="radio
"][name="correct_option"]\');\n\n    options.forEach((option, index) => {\n        option.addEventListener("change", function () {\n            // Aktivieren Sie das zugeh\xc3\xb6rige 
Textfeld, wenn die Option ausgew\xc3\xa4hlt ist\n            const textField = optionsList.querySelector(`input[type="text"][name="option_${index + 1}"]`);\n            textField.disab
led = !this.checked;\n\n            // Deaktivieren Sie alle anderen Textfelder\n            optionsList.querySelectorAll(\'input[type="text"]\').forEach((otherTextField, otherIndex) =
> {\n                if (otherIndex !== index) {\n                    otherTextField.disabled = false;\n                }\n            });\n        });\n    });\n</script>\n\n\n\n        <!-- Uhranzeige mit JavaScript -->\n        <div class="clock" id="clock"></div>\n\n\n            <script>\n                // JavaScript, um die Uhrzeit anzuzeigen\n               
 function updateClock() {\n                    const clockElement = document.getElementById("clock");\n                    const now = new Date();\n                    const hours = no
w.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");\n                    const minutes = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");\n                    const seconds = now.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0");\n                    const date = now.toDateString();\n                    clockElement.textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds} - ${date}`;\n             
   }\n\n                // Aktualisieren Sie die Uhr jede Sekunde\n                setInterval(updateClock, 1000);\n\n                // Initial die Uhrzeit anzeigen\n                u
pdateClock();\n            </script>\n        <br>\n\n\n        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy3
8MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>\n        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJ
oft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>\n        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>\n    </body>\n</html>\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stderr teardown -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas how make the test correct? As explained before the manual testing gets everything written in the data base and the redirect is there.